# Progress Bar in Windows Phone 8 App

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8

I want to add a progress bar to my application when certain data is being processed.

In XAML:

```
ProgressBar x:Name="progressBar1"  Value="{Binding progressPercent}" Maximum="100" Margin="10,209,10,63" Grid.Row="5" RenderTransformOrigin="0.5,0.5">
```

In C#:

```
private void Button_Click_1(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    IsolatedStorageFile isf = IsolatedStorageFile.GetUserStoreForApplication();
    progressBar1.IsIndeterminate = true;    

    progressBar1.Value = progressPercent;

    for(int i=0;i<5;i++)
    {
        if(count[i] == 1)
        {
            t=1;
            break;
        }
    } // and the code continues
```

But the `IsDeterminate` property does not become true when I used a breakpoint to check it.
Could anyone tell me what's the issue?

Comment: Where did you set the breakpoint? The UI won't update until the function is finished, which could be a while and you could be setting the value back at the end. CPU processing should be done on a seperate thread.

Comment: Even though I don't use the breakpoint , the Progress Bar does not show up in any case. 
I used the break point in this line :  progressBar1.Value = progressPercent;

Answer (score 0):

I Cannot see the whole xaml of the page. and code behind. I can check 2 things.

1. I will check the xaml and make sure that progress bar is not under any other control or out of the bound of screen. As I can see that your progress bar Grid.Row is 5 and top is set to 209. it might be the case that it is out of the bound of the screen.
2. there might another piece of cod that is setting Intermediate state to false in the code file.